# Any way to ensure JMS eventing occurs or to tell JMS eventing to start and complete at a certain time?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I am running an integration test using Arquillian in an EAR file that uses CDI and JMS where I am dependent on the results of JMS eventing for the integration tests. I found that I cannot control when the JMS eventing occurs. Sometimes, JMS eventing occurs before a particular test starts which is the result I want. But sometimes I find the JMS eventing occurs after the test. Is there any way to tell JMS that it should begin at a particular time or to complete by a particular time? Is there any way to ask JMS whether a particular event has occurred or not?  Is there any way to tell a test in Arquillian to wait for JMS to complete before starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved the issue was to add the following call after sending my JMS event:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With the above code, the JMS eventing is able to complete before the start of the next test. This works consistently.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Essentially what you're asking for is synchronous behavior with an asynchronous technology.

I don't believe I've ever seen guaranteed timeliness in an JMS specs, so while the messages will be delivered, it's up to the JMS provider and the listener receiving the messages as to when it actually happens.

In terms of trying to complete by a specific time, after the message is delivered it's up to your processing to determine how short or how long the processing is.  Other than putting in your own timeout logic, JMS itself is not going to do it.

I'll ask a real basic question: is JMS really the correct technology for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you suggest some alternatives to JMS?

Comment: Sounds like you need an ESB of some sort, even something light-weight like Mule might provide the necessary functionality.